# Orbeon CE Log4j

Tags: orbeon

Is there a plan to update Orbeon CE logging to log4j 2.17 and if so, when?

We are aware that the current log4j 1.X version is not susceptible to the recent vulnerability, but other vulnerabilities are still present.

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms 2021.1 CE, coming out soon, will include Log4j 2.17 (or newer if they release yet another version in the next few days).

The vulnerabilities affecting Log4j 1.x affect things like SocketAppender and SMTP. We recommend for now that you don't use any networking feature with Log4j in your log4j.xml. Just use plain logging to files. If you do that, you are quite safe with Log4j 1.x, and possibly safer than with any version of Log4j 2 where vulnerabilities apparently keep being found :(

We haven't yet decided whether we would release fixes for earlier CE versions as the issues can be addressed entirely via configuration.

Comment: Eric - does the Orbeon Forms 2021.1 CE have the log4j 2.17.1

Comment: Yes it does use 2.17.1.